# Hiking trails in Pennsylvania

Tags: hiking, pennsylvania

My friends and I are looking for a solid hiking trail in Pennsylvania.

This will be our second trip, but we are in reasonable shape and had little issue our first time around.

We are from Michigan, so the western part of the state would be nice, but we are not opposed to going to the East side of the state if better trailing is found there.

We experienced rolling uplands in the UP with an abundance of waterfalls, which was very pleasant. This is the type of terrain we are looking for.

We plan on trekking for 3-4 days.

Comment: In addition to where you're located / where you want to hike, how long a hike do you want? Is this an afternoon, an overnight camp, or a week-long trek?

Comment: @kdgregory Sorry for leaving it open! I just added an edit (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a longer trip in SW PA, the [Laurel Highlands Hiking Trail](http://www.dcnr.state.pa.us/stateparks/lhht/) is an option of about the right length.  The question is very broad and you could probably get better answers at a trail directory like [AllTrails PA](http://alltrails.com/us/pennsylvania).

You will find the Great Allegheny Passage boring for hiking.

If you like lots of waterfalls and don't mind driving east, check out [Ricketts Glen](http://www.dcnr.state.pa.us/stateparks/findapark/rickettsglen/) and [Seven Tubs](http://alltrails.com/trail/us/pennsylvania/seven-tubs-nature-area). Those are single-day or shorter, but beautiful.

There's also the north-central [Old Logger's Path](https://www.alltrails.com/trail/us/pennsylvania/old-loggers-path) you might consider for a few days.  Coming from Michigan you might combine that with a stargazing visit to [Cherry Springs State Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_Springs_State_Park) (weather permitting, of course).

Comment: I just edited the q so it's less broad! If that helps narrow I'd appreciate that, but thank you for the useful link (:

Comment: Your edit is confusing: "the western part of the state would be nice, but we are not opposed to going to the West side of the state"  
Assuming you prefer western PA, same answer but with a couple waterfall-heavy sites in the eastern part added.

Comment: I meant "..opposed to going to the East side of the state..", just a typo haha. Thanks for the update, much appreciated!(:

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what part of Pennsylvania you are in, The [Great Allegheny Passage](http://www.atatrail.org/tmi/maps.cfm) offers the option to walk or bicycle from Pittsburgh to Washington DC. It is mostly rail to trail, and relatively flat.

On the Eastern side of Pennsylvania is 200+ miles of the [Appalachian Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_Trail#Pennsylvania) I have not traveled it so can not speak to it's difficulty.

Comment: The AT in PA is flat and rocky. It can be hard on the feet as the rocks comes out of the ground in weird and annoying angles.

Comment: I just added an edit if that helps narrow down trails you may know!